# Mapbox GL add json as data source

Tags: json, return, mapbox, geojson

I'm currently working on a project that involves Mapbox GL. I'm getting a json file from the server with quiet a lot of location points. This file is having the following structure:

```
{"location": {"lat": 50.62914, "lon": 5.61972}}
```

Now I want to place them on a layer in mapbox. Problem is mapbox only supports GeoJSON. So I'm trying to fix this with the following workaround.

```
function updateMap(data) {
    console.log("Updating map with " + data.length + " users");
    // Converting my json file into a Geojson format by returning type:point, coordinates for every json entry
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        return {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [d.location.lon, d.location.lat]
        };
    });
};
```

I'm not sure if this is even possible, so please correct me if I'm wrong. I think I have to return it outside the forEach loop otherwise I will only get the first result.

Next up is adding this geojson file as a source for the layer. Something which looks like this:

```
map.on('load', function () {
    map.addSource('point', {
        "type": "geojson",
        "data": //need to add the points that I returned above here.
    });

    map.addLayer({
        "id": "point",
        "source": "point",
        "type": "circle",
        "paint": {
            "circle-radius": 8,
            "circle-color": "#000"
        }
    });
});
```

Only problem is I don't know how to retrieve all the data from the return in the updateMap function.

Thanks for your help in advance! I hope this is possible tho.

Kind regards,

Wouter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GeoJSON is extremely sensitive when it comes to formatting your features. It might be worthwhile, rather than using a "return", to push each value to an array.

```
function updateMap(data) {
    var test = [];
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        test.push(JSON.parse('{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": ['+d.location.lon+','+ d.location.lat+']}}'));
    });
}
```

Then change the map.addSource to look like this:

```
map.on('load', function() {
    map.addSource("point", {
        "type": "geojson",
        "data": {
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "features": test
        }
    });
    map.addLayer({
        "id": "point",
        "type": "circle",
        "source": "point",
        "paint": {
            "circle-radius": 8,
            "circle-color": "#000"
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yea thanks. It's the correct answer. But had it already working. Still starting to hate mapbox more and more tho.

Comment: Completely understand. We seem to have a lot of issues where the icons don't load 100% of the time. Drives me nuts

Comment: Yea, I couldn't edit the colors of my circle based on values in my json file because I had to convert it to geojson. I lost connection between two values. Had to manually cut up my json file into pieces and add 4 layers onto the map.